# Should Spring Cloud configuration for multiple microservices reside in individual git repositories?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I'm not sure If I understand the Spring Cloud Config documentation correctly.

Spring Cloud Config is the central configuration management service, allowing to manage configuration of multiple services within my application landscape. Say I have two microservices `ms1` and `ms2`. In the spirit of Spring cloud config, should I keep the configuration files (`application.yml`) for these services in separate repositories? Or is it rather suggested to keep them in the same repository, but name the files individually, i.e. `ms1.yml`, `ms2.yml`?

Answer (score -1):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/psramkumar/spring-config.git
          searchPaths: '{application}'
          basedir: /home/myhome/cfgserv
          skipSslValidation: true
          username: gitread
          refreshRate: 300
```

make sure to match the folder name with spring.application.name in client
eg:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice1
```

access your config server as
http://localhost:8888/config/**development**/microservice1

where development is environment name as Branch name

config server : https://github.com/psramkumar/spring-config-server.git

config repos:https://github.com/psramkumar/spring-config.git

Comment: This isn’t an answer to the question asked